# What's difference between .NetCoreApp and .NetStandard.Library?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

.Net Core 1.0 has been released couple days ago, and i've started playing with it. I've created simple solution, with one project (class library => .NetStandard.Library) and second, console application (.NetCoreApp). The point is, console application has reference to library, but i cant use types form that library. Are those two frameworks incompatible? Am i missing something?

project.json for console application:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "ConsoleApplicationLibrary": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

project.json for library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

I've figured it out, that it works, and code compiles, but visual studio still highlights types from library as unknown.

Comment: Did you restore packages for the application?

Comment: Between the subject and the post, you are asking too many questions. Narrow it down to one or risk having your question closed.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that .Net Core is expecting `ConsoleApplicationLibrary` to be a NuGet package. If you want to reference a project, use `"ConsoleApplicationLibrary": {"target": "project", "version": "1.0.0-*"}`.

After you do that, don't forget to restore packages.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's strange, but after disabling resharper, restarting VS and rebuilding solution, it works fine. It seems there is prolem with resharper support for .net core. (resharper v.9.1.3). From this: [resharper ultimate blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/05/27/resharper-ultimate-2016-2-eap-kicks-off/) i understand that only ultimate version supports .net core for now.

Comment: Why would you expect ReSharper from a year ago to support .Net Core, which was released less than a month ago?

Comment: a mix of future proofing, naivety, and herbal medicine? :)

Answer (score 1):

**.NetCoreApp** is a platform and **.NetStandard.Library** is a library supposed to be cross platform (portable class library) for various .NET platforms runtimes.

You can include a direct reference (package) of NetStandard.Library in any of your .NET platform project that is supported, for ex .NETCoreApp (Dot Net Core 1.X)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it turned out I needed to update Resharper to it's latest version. I had v9.1.1 so I updated it to 2016.3.2 and that fixed the issue.